# pop up modal not working properly

Tags: html, css

i am making a website for my college as a project.To show you i have hosted the same on a free 
hosting site. link http://vivace.net23.net/ .Now in the informal section of menu i wanted to put a pop up modal here is the fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/karn21/73QXx/.

Click Me

```
   <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>

    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

But on click it is not working.Please help me

Comment: It's working perfectly on the ones I tried (Chrome, Firefox, IE)...

Comment: no what i meant to say is that when you place the pop modal in the website i have created( in informal section of menu) it is not working..

Comment: I don't see the search box anywhere on the coding of your website.  What activates it?

Comment: i simply tried placing the modal pop up code in my project in informal section.but it is not working

Comment: Ok but it is not even in the source of the page.

Comment: yeah i tried it on my laptop..posted it to ask for help..i am not able to debug this

Comment: The problem is that you just need to actually code it into the page.

Comment: i did that..it is not working

Comment: If you can show me where in the source code of the website you have implemented the code in the JSFiddle, I will be able to help, but I don't see it anywhere within the source.

Comment: ill give you the updated links...sorry for the wrong link..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your JavaScript forcing hashtagged links to scroll is causing the problems for the popup.  You may need to either remove that aspect or change the method that you use to show the popup.

Comment: do you know any alternate way for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting it as a target, you could set an `onclick` event for the `Click Me` button that triggers a JavaScript function to append the id `target` to the div (or another class).  Then, change `.modalDialog:target` to `.modalDialog.target`.  Then, just remove the class when the close button is clicked.

New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73QXx/2/

That shouldn't interfere with your hastag scrolling script.

Also, if you still wanted it to appear as a link, you can add this:

**CSS**:

```
a {
    color: #0645AD;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:visited {
    color: #663366;
}
```

**EDIT**:

This line is only supported by IE11+:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Here is an alternative that you can add using an HTML `IF` to check if the version is IE10 or less:

```
pointer-events: none; => z-index: -1;
pointer-events: auto; => z-index: 10; /*This may need to be increased depending
                                      on the elements on the page*/
```

New Fiddle for IE9 (and many other versions including anything that the old version can support): http://jsfiddle.net/73QXx/3/

However, the downside and why this should not be used for anything except IE9 or lower (which is possible with HTML `IF`) is that the box suddenly appears instead of fading in.

Comment: this thing is not working in ie9. the whole menu froze.Now link is working.How to fix this?but It is working fine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: So your method is working in IE 9 but this method is working in all other browsers and newer IE versions?

Comment: the method you gave is working in chrome and firefox properly but not in ie9.Using that code all links stopped working in ie9.

Comment: Ok I can't fix it right now because I'm bus, but I will later.

Comment: sure..but please do help

Comment: Oh wow... Sorry, that must have been confusing.  I misspelled busy.

Comment: I have updated it to support earlier versions of IE.